# Joomla 2.5 - Password to backend lost

Tags: joomla, password

Can I recover the backend password for Joomla 2.5?

Answer (score 2):

No - Joomla! does not store the password.

It stores a hash of the password with a salt.

To reset the password you could use one of the tools on the [Joomla! Extension Directory (JED)](http://extensions.joomla.org) in the [Security Section](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/tools/security-tools/).

We tend to do it manually, but I've heard that people have used the "[Reset Admin Password](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/tools/security-tools/13785)" tool successfully.

Comment: cppl. I thank you very much for your kindness! I shall try. Just one note. This Joomla's policy that makes it hard to recover a lost password seems to be very unusual. Even strong and very well reputed companies like e.g. Google (Gmail) and PayPal (a Bank) let you recover your Password. They do implement a very secure way to do that but they do!!! Regards. Bruno

Comment: The only password Joomla! doesn't let you recover is the root Super User password, of course to recover a password you need a login module published somewhere (it's the module that has the links for recovering your password).

Answer (score 2):

To change a user password manually:

1. Login to your database
2. Select the database where Joomla is installed
3. Select the table "Users"
4. Choose the user you want to edit
5. Click "Edit"
6. Identify the "Password" field
7. Choose "MD5" from the drop-down.
8. Enter your new password.
9. Press "OK" to save the changes.

[I can not post images because of a lack of reputation.]

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you could most likely crack it with John the Ripper (JTR).  You may be able to download safely from Foundstone.